# Sorting collections using a Map with string and separate class

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I am basically trying to sort an input file of Students and Marks into alphabetic and numeric order. I have 4 classes, however I cannot manage to get it to print the student with the mark in any order. Let alone in a alphabetic and numeric order. Any help in how I can get the results printing as a total or any help at all is greatly appreciated.
Below is the code I have used for the 4 classes and the input file.

Input File:

```
Simon 4
Anna 10
Simon 4
Anna 9
Anna 5
Edward 10
```

Code:

```
package part1;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, StudentMath> map = new HashMap<String, StudentMath>();
        String input = "data/results.txt";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(input));
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String[] in = line.split(" ");
            String name = in[0];
            int mark = Integer.parseInt(in[1]);
            //System.out.println(name + ":" + mark);
            StudentMath stud = map.get(name);
            if (stud == null) {
                stud = new StudentMath(name, mark);
                map.put(name, stud);
                stud.sum(mark);
            }

        }
        for (String s: map.keySet()){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}

package part1;

public class StudentMath extends Main {

    public String name;
    public int mark;

    public StudentMath(String s, int n) {
        name = s;
        mark = n;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;

    }
    public int getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public int sum() {
       int tot = mark + mark;
       return tot;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof StudentMath) {
            StudentMath m = (StudentMath) o;
            return (name == m.name) && (mark == m.mark);

        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

package part1;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class NameCompare implements Comparator<StudentMath> {
    public int compare(StudentMath g1, StudentMath g2) {
        return g1.name.compareTo(g2.name);
    }
}


package part1;


import java.util.Comparator;

public class MarkCompare implements Comparator<StudentMath>{

    public int compare(StudentMath g1, StudentMath g2) {
        return g2.mark - g1.mark;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what exactly are you having problems with

Answer (score 2):

A `HashMap` is an *unordered* collection, so it does not define an ordering over it's keys. That is why you get your output in random order.

You could try using an ordered collection type, such as a `List` (`ArrayList` or `LinkedList`), or if you really need to have a `Map` then you could look at the `TreeMap` class. `TreeMap` is a `Map` implementation that knows how to sort its keys. Note that `TreeMap` is not able to sort by value, so it probably isn't the right data structure to use here because you won't be able to (easily) use it to sort by mark.

I won't give you code because this is clearly homework, but hopefully that will get you on the right track.

EDIT: To address the comment below: **ordered** is not the same as **sorted**. To actually sort a `List` into the order you want, take a look at the `Collections.sort` methods.

Comment: A `list` is not an ordered collection.Unless you are refering to the insertion order

Comment: @user384706: Um...yes it is. The behaviour of the `Iterator` obtained from a list is well defined: the list is always in some known order and (unless the underlying data changes) the iterator will always return items in the same order. A `HashMap` does not provide this guarantee, hence it is "unordered". A *sorted* collection is always an *ordered* collection, but an ordered collection is not necessarily sorted.

Comment: The thing is, I need to send the mark to the StudentMath class, calculate the total, and return it to the Main class. However, I cannot get this to work effectively.

Comment: You've got the right idea by looking for the student's name and creating a new `StudentMath` object if it's not found. Now think about what happens when you look up the map and it *doesn't* return null. What does your code do? What *should* it do?

Comment: @CameronSkinner:`the list is always in some known order and the iterator returns items in the same order`.Yes but this is the insertion order not the natural order.From your comment and answer I am still not clear on what order you are talking about

Comment: @user384706: You are confusing *ordered* with *sorted*. Ordered means that the ordering is defined: a `Set` is *unordered* because two iterators are allowed to return items in a different order if they wish, even if the underlying collection has not changed. A `List` is *ordered* because two iterators must always return items in the same order if the underlying collection has not changed. Insertion order and natural order refer to *sorted* lists - that's not the same thing as *ordered*.

Answer (score 1):

Never ever compare Strings using "==" always use "equals" to compare.
in the line

```
return (name == m.name) && (mark == m.mark);
```

change it to

```
return (name.equals(m.name))&& (mark == m.mark);
```